# mysqldump sql file save without content

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-cli

i have this php script.when i run the script mysqldump, The file got saved but the content is empty. Any help is appreciated.

thank you.

```
$filename = "backup-" .  date("YmdHis") .  ".sql";
$pathfile = public_path('database') .'/' .$filename;

exec('mysqldump -u'.env('DB_USERNAME').' -p'.env('DB_PASSWORD').' '.env('DB_DATABASE'). ' > ' . $pathfile);

echo 'done';
```

No Error is printing, But the file is empty

Comment: Add param 2 to the exec command so you can see the output like `exec('mysqldump -u'.env('DB_USERNAME').' -p'.env('DB_PASSWORD').' '.env('DB_DATABASE'). ' > ' . $pathfile, $OUTPUT_ARRAY);`

Comment: i add this line and out put was $OUTPUT_ARRAY is 127 . and still same problam.thank you

Comment: result is"int(127)"

Comment: still return code is 0

Comment: bash: mysqldump: command not found

Comment: im using mac os and this is in laravel

Comment: So it is not on the PATH. Fix that OR add the complete path to the mysqldump call, which would be safer shoudl you ever move this code

Comment: i set path and now get this error

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect

Comment: Did you set a password on the MySQL `root`account?

Comment: yes i set password

Comment: Are you sure `DB_PASSWORD` is set to the right password

Comment: Thank You So much.

This answer works for me.
So it is not on the PATH. Fix that OR add the complete path to the mysqldump call, which would be safer shoudl you ever move this code 

If you can put it as answer i can mark it as answer. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `mysqldump` processor is in a folder that is on your PATH or you have to add the complete path to the `mysqldump` processor to the PHP call to the processor.